# Jquery code - almost figured it out

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been trying all day to get this to work and have been very unsuccessful. I am new to jquery and could use some help combining jquery functions.

I am using the following code for a slideshow:

```
$(function() {
    $("#foo3").carouFredSel({
        items: 1,
        prev: {
            button: "#foo3_prev",
            key: "left"
        },
        next: {
            button: "#foo3_next",
            key: "right"
        },
        auto: {
            duration: 1000
        },
        scroll: {
            items: 1,
            duration: 1000,
            mousewheel: true,
            wipe: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            onAfter: function() {
              if ( $(this).triggerHandler( "currentPosition" ) == 0 ) {
              $(this).trigger( "pause" );
            }
        }
    },
  })
  .parent()
  .css("margin", "auto");       
});
```

and have been unsuccessful in trying to merge the following function into it:

```
 $("#foo3").carouFredSel({
auto    : false,
scroll  : {
    duration : 0.5
}
}).find("li").click(function() {
var deviation = parseInt( $("#foo3_deviation").val() );
$("#foo3").trigger("slideTo", [$(this), deviation]);
}).css("cursor", "pointer");
```

I need to maintain the settings in the first set of code, but add the functionality of clicking on the slideshow (li) to advance to the next image.

I don't know if you need more information to help, but if so please let me know.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

**FOR CLARIFICATION:**

I need to add the last bit of code starting with .find(li).click(function()

into the first section of code to make my existing slideshow http://2938.sandbox.i3dthemes.net/index.html function with clicking on the image as well as the auto scroll.

**REVISION:**

I MANAGED TO GET THIS FAR...

```
$(function() {

        $("#foo3").carouFredSel({
            auto    : true,
            scroll  : {
            items: 1,
                duration: 1000,
                mousewheel: true,
                wipe: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
               onAfter: function() {
            if ( $(this).triggerHandler( "currentPosition" ) == 0 ) {
              $(this).trigger( "pause" );
             }
          }},
            }).find("li").click(function() {
            var deviation = parseInt( $("#foo3_deviation").val() );
            $("#foo3").trigger("slideTo", [$(this), deviation]);
            }).css("cursor", "pointer");
          });
```

AND NOW NEED TO FIGURE OUT HOW TO GET THIS SNIPPET FROM THE FIRST PIECE OF CODE BACK IN...

```
    }).parent()
    .css("margin", "auto");
```

Can anyone help...?

Comment: It looks like you may not be aware that method chaining is not *required* in jQuery. Often, chaining makes things less readable. Also, your second code snippet seems cut off in the wrong place..it begins in the middle of a configuration object.

Comment: @zetlen - I have no idea what you mean... I apologize for my ignorance. The whole second snippet is added above.

Comment: No need to apologize. It does make it more difficult to help. I recommend that you go to jsfiddle.com and learn how to create a working demo of the problem you're trying to solve. Then, you can link to a jsfiddle here, and let your code speak for itself. People trying to help can simply modify your code and show you their modifications, perhaps explaining what the problem was. This way, you don't have to worry about struggling to articulate problems and solutions.

Comment: @zetlen - I have tried figuring out jsfiddle earlier this week and was unsuccessful. Would a link to the site help?

Comment: Sure. I'm not sure, though, what your ultimate goal is. Why do you want or need to "combine" these two scripts? What is your page not doing that you want it to do?

Comment: @zetlen - trying to accomplish this http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/examples/custom-events.php with the current show I have located here: http://2938.sandbox.i3dthemes.net/index.html - sorry should have said the first one on that page.

Comment: @zetlen - I figured out how to get the code from the second part into the first, however I cannot find a way to complete it. Can you help me. I have revised the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {

  $("#foo3").carouFredSel({
    auto    : true,
    scroll  : {
      items       : 1,
      duration    : 1000,
      mousewheel  : true,
      wipe        : true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      onAfter     : function() {
        if ( $(this).triggerHandler( "currentPosition" ) == 0 ) {
          $(this).trigger( "pause" );
        }
      }
    }
  })
  .find("li")
  .click(function() {
    var deviation = parseInt( $("#foo3_deviation").val() );
    $("#foo3").trigger("slideTo", [$(this), deviation]);
  })
  .css("cursor", "pointer")
  .end()
  .parent()
  .css('margin','auto');

});
```

Every time you run another method (e.g. `.css("cursor","pointer")`) directly after a previous method has completed, you're doing what's called [chaining](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/). jQuery methods are functions which return the jQuery object they operated on. But some methods, like `.find()`, actually change the underlying elements of the object that is returned. You can think of a method like `.css` as **returning the original jQuery object**, and a method like `.find()` as **returning a new jQuery object**. When you're looking through the jQuery docs, note what each method says it returns.

For more readable code, you can avoid the chaining so you always know what you're operating on. Like this:

```
$(function() {

  var $carousel = $('#foo3'); // caching the initial jQuery object in a variable.

  $carousel.carouFredSel({
    auto    : true,
    scroll  : {
      items       : 1,
      duration    : 1000,
      mousewheel  : true,
      wipe        : true,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      onAfter     : function() {
        if ( $(this).triggerHandler( "currentPosition" ) == 0 ) {
          $(this).trigger( "pause" );
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // change the css of the carousel's parent.
  $carousel.parent().css('margin','auto');

  // modify each <li> child of the carousel.
  $carousel.find("li")
    .click(function() {
      var deviation = parseInt( $("#foo3_deviation").val() );
      $("#foo3").trigger("slideTo", [$(this), deviation]);
    })
    .css("cursor", "pointer");

});
```

I know this is tough to understand if you're just writing a tiny bit of code and you don't care about the internals, but if you know more about what jQuery is doing, you'll be able to work with it a lot faster.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It always helps to understand the reasons why something works or how it works (even if it is just a little bit of code). I don't suppose you know how to make it click right "or" left with the slideto <li> trigger? Currently it only clicks to the right although it does have a circular function with in scroll and wipe (goes forward and backwards). If not, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Since I wasn't able to get any help and struggled through this with success, I thought I would post the results in case someone else using the caroufredsel needed help accomplishing the same effects.

Here is the completed code:

```
        $(function() {

        $("#foo3").carouFredSel({
            auto    : true,
            scroll  : {
            items: 1,
                duration: 1000,
                mousewheel: true,
                wipe: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
               onAfter: function() {
            if ( $(this).triggerHandler( "currentPosition" ) == 0 ) {
              $(this).trigger( "pause" );
             }
          }},
            }).find("li").click(function() {
            var deviation = parseInt( $("#foo3_deviation").val() );
            $("#foo3").trigger("slideTo", [$(this), deviation]);
            }).css("cursor", "pointer");
            $("#foo3").parent().css("margin", "auto");
        });
```

Comment: Oh dear. You beat me. I'm sorry it took me so long! You have indeed figured out a way around this. My solution is different but gives you the same effect: the `.end()` method "backs out out" of the `.find("li")` which was changing the context of your jQuery chain, which means that your `.css()` method was applying itself to the child `li` elements instead of the `#foo3` element like you wanted.